# How to get all user accounts under "Profiles Missing from Import"?

Tags: user-profile

Is it possible to get all users under **Profiles Missing from Import**? I try to enter the wildcard character (*) by the GUI, but it don't work. Is there another solution?

If there is a powershell command, it is also ok.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just enter the first letter of your domain (or your whole domain) and it will return the results.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a PowerShell cmdlet but if you have access to the Database it might be quicker to find that information through below T-SQL (at least that's how I feel it :-))

replace "SP2013_UPA_Profile" with your UPA database name.

Hope this helps!

```
SELECT [PartitionID]
      ,[RecordID]
      ,[UserID]
      ,[NTName]
      ,[PreferredName]
      ,[Email]
      ,[SID]
      ,[Manager]
      ,[SipAddress]
      ,[LastUpdate]
      ,[LastUserUpdate]
      ,[LastImported]
      ,[bDeleted]
      ,[DataSource]
      ,[MasterRecordID]
      ,[ProfileSubtypeID]
      ,[DSGuid]
      ,[PictureUrl]
  FROM [SP2013_UPA_Profile].[dbo].[UserProfile_Full] with (nolock)
  where bDeleted <> 0
```

Comment: I would like to use this select query, but is not supported to do that. Was you talking about this powershell script?

$upa = Get-spserviceapplication -name 'User Profile Service Application' Set-SPProfileServiceApplication $upa -GetNonImportedObjects $true

Comment: Bad idea, not supported. Don't do this.

Comment: Is there another solution in powershell or programmatically(c#)?